# Error: ITMS-90338 - Non-public API Usage in App Submission

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode beta version 15 for Flutter app.

I recently updated my Flutter app and successfully submitted it to App Store Connect. However, I received an email notification mentioning the error code ITMS-90338, indicating non-public API usage.
[image]

Things which i've already tried

1. I've tried uploading it using transporter
2. Tried using this also

`flutter clean`

`rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework`

`flutter build ios --release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit apps to the App Store using beta tools.

Rebuild your app with Xcode 14 and resubmit.

Apple will provide guidance when an Xcode 15 release candidate can be used to submit apps.